# Clear input text on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have three components.

1. `SearchBarInput` which is a controlled component based on Material UI OutlinedInput. As props it takes `onClickClear`.
2. `Input` which renders the `SearchBarInput` and passes to it the `onClickClear`
3. `App` which renders the `Input` component and passes to it a `handleClickClear` function.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-allen-fprpd

When the user inputs anything in the `Input`, an X icon appears. If the user clicks it, it sets the state of the input to `undefined`. Thus, the state is correctly cleared.
**However**, it does not clear the UI of the input from what the user has typed.

What I am trying to achieve is a similar behaviour of `<input type="search">` in plain html

See:

[image: Visual Explanation]

Comment: add material ui to the tags, it's important to know it to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just about this function over here:

```
const handleClickClear = () => {
    setInputText(undefiend);
  };
```

in App.tsx
you need to replace it with this one over here

```
const handleClickClear = () => {
    setInputText("");
  };
```

and we have also passed down the textInput value from the App.tsc all the way down to SearchBarInput.tsx and add it as a value to the input it self

and you can find my solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-payne-2727u?file=/src/App.tsx:377-436

Comment: That alone doesn't work unfortunately :/ you also have to pass the  `inputText` as a prop.

Comment: try these edits here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-payne-2727u?file=/src/App.tsx:377-436

Comment: Ah you also added `value` as a prop. That was missing in OP's code sandbox. It might be worth mentioning that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. What I was missing was passing the value as props from App to Input to SearchBarInput

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ives-wc74h?file=/src/App.tsx:376-729). I ended up passing `inputText` down as a prop (added it to the necessary interfaces) and used that as value for the input. You also need to make `inputText` an empty string when you hit the clear icon. If it's `undefined` it doesn't update the input component. See below.

**App.tsx**

```
...

 const handleClickClear = () => {
    setInputText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input
        showClearIcon={!!inputText}
        onSearchBarChange={(event) => handleSearchBarChange(event)}
        onClickClear={handleClickClear}
        inputText={inputText}
      />
      <br />
      <p>My text: {inputText} </p>
    </div>
```

Then in the child components declare `inputText` as a prop in the interfaces and pass the prop down to the child components.

```
interface Props {
  ...
  inputText: string | undefined;
  ...
}
```

Finally, add it as the value passed to `OutlinedInput` in `SearchBarInput`.

**SearchBarInput.tsx**

```
  <OutlinedInput
      type="text"
      value={inputText}
      onChange={onChange}
   ...
   />
```

Comment: Thanks. What I was missing was passing the value as props from App to Input to SearchBarInput

Answer (score 1):

first, be sure to set your `inputText` to be **string** type only. if you set to be also `undefined` you will face error `A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled` if it's value becomes `undefined`.

in this way your setState should be:

```
const handleClickClear = () => {
    setInputText("");
  };
```

second, you need to pass down `inputText` as prop to `Input` then to `SeachInput`. and remember to also set `value` prop type to be **string**.

**passing to Input**

```
  <Input
    value={inputText}
    // other props
```

**passing to SearchInput**

```
<SearchBarInput
  value={value}
  // other props
```

now `SearchBarInput` will have value updated accordingly.